# Problems with Blender3D and ATI graphics

Tags: 10.04, graphics, ati, blender

I recently upgraded to 10.04, then to an ATI graphics card (I used the internal graphics port before) and now noticed that blender is behaving very strange. Menus don't work or very slowly, fragments on the screen and so on. I didn't try anything else because it's impossible to use.

The card is an ATI Radeon HD 4650.

Did anyone experience similar problems ?

Comment: Are you using the vesa, ati or the free driver?

Comment: If you are experiencing these problems then you might want to consider creating a bug report. It could be a real problem and I am sure that the devs would like to know.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2):

I have an ATI Radeon HD 4350 with the open source drivers, and Blender seems to work fine on Ubuntu 10.10 (with visual effects enabled).

You could try a 10.10 live CD to see if the problem still exists there for you.

Another thing you can test, on your 10.04 install, is to disable the "visual effects" in the Appearance configuration dialog.  Sometimes these effects interfere with applications that also use OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

I have an ATI Radeon 4850 and I use a logitech trackball mouse. My OS is Ubuntu 10.04. I tried starting blender using this command from a terminal:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 blender
```

That made things somewhat better, but did not really fix the problem. Disabling visual effects in the appearance settings fixed everything (after i restarted blender without the LIBGL... setting).

I would have just voted up the above answer, but I don't have enough points yet, and this was a very frustrating problem for me so I wanted to say something. Thank you JanC, your answer helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Two things I would suggest:
Use the fglrx driver if you are using the open-source driver,
Try using Blender 2.5, as this is much better than older versions, and should be so as well with the cases where 2.4x was troublesome (it was known to be on ATI cards).

Answer (score 0):

Could You show the display of Yoyr xorg.conf.new file?
([HowToCreate Xorg file](https://askubuntu.com/a/97855/41480))

One more thing - did You chck if 3D rendering works?

```
glxinfo | grep -i direct
```

(might bee required to install mesa utils)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's it's somthing that i problem with the Blender that you have install and it need to be restart that the problem can be solve but if that doesn't work you can always test to see if the OS is slow itself if not i think it's the program.