# Dual Monitor with high resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, dualhead

I got some trouble with my dual monitor setup.
My monitors:
Iiyama 22" 1680x1050
Samsung SyncMaster TA350 24" 1920x1080
My graphics card is an AMD Radeon 5750 and I installed the additional AMD driver correctly. I used to have the Iiyama and another 19" (1280x1024) Monitor, both connected via DVI and everything worked well. So now, I bought a Samsung 24" monitor, connected it via dsub and ubuntu says that the resolution is too high. So I changed the virtual screen resolution to 3600x1080 in xorg.conf but after a reboot I had to detach my new monitor - only the 22" Iiyama works.
How can I get my Samsung (and my dual monitor setup) to work?

Thx for help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did You try editing xorg.conf in such manner that You added the second monitor manually?
([try this fr reference](https://askubuntu.com/a/97855/41480))

Comment: No, the monitor was detected automatically… I just added the new virtual screen size.

Comment: Ok, so first (before trying to change xorg.conf) try to set Your virtual monitor res as it has been before. And connect both monitors and try to make it work by making the resolution a bit lower. Are You able do make them both work at low resolution?

Comment: Just if somebody is searching for the same problem, my error message is:
The selected configuratation for displays coud not be applied
required virtual size does not fit available size: requested=(3360, 150), minimum=(320,200), maximum=(1680, 1680)
So now, i will try it. :)

Comment: Ok, I found out what the problem was. My configuration under "Screen->Display->Virtual" was 3600x1080. But it required 3600x1920… I think it has something to do with display rotation but I am not sure. But it works now. Thanks for your help! :) I hope that will help somebody.