# Gnome Shell dual monitor issue (minor)

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, command-line

I am experiencing a minor issue with Gnome Shell and 2 screens. I'll do my best to explain it:

Both screens work the way I like, no issues with that. But, screens appear to be few pixels to the right meaning that I can just see right edge of the screen on the left side.

The problem isn't critical, but having a fix would make it look better.

Thanks for replies already in advance,

Lassi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by setting the position of screen on the left using xrandr
(xrandr --output LVDS --pos -8x312)**

Answer (score 0):

Please [create xorg.conf.new](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96753/two-ati-radeon-cards-on-10-04) file and change there display size option in the manner that will make Your screen appear properly.
Then reboot.