# runt integrated intel graphics card + nvidia pcie graphics card?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, graphics

Its days I am searching for information/help. Is this possible at all? I am running Ubuntu 11.10 on an intel core i3 530 on a intel dh55hc mainboard. I have 2 monitors attached, one on dvi and one on hdmi. I want to ad a third or eaven a fourth monitor using an additional graphics card nvidia in pcie slot. I cant get an image on all monitors at the same time. I am wondering if this is possible at all? Any ideas where I can get information about this?

Thanks in advance

Roberto

Answer (score 1):

In general there's no problem in setting for example two cards and 4 or 6 monitors on Linux. However when there is speak about intel cards problems begin. Integrated intel cards usualy do not cooperate with PCI cards and so on. This forum is full of posts concerning this issue. So Combining Intel card with other card might be difficult or impossible. But...

First of all, get into BIOS and check if Your mainboard allows to use two VGA cards at the same time. If Yes, set this option to allow to do so. Then boot to Ubuntu and see if it detects all VGA cards:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

It should give both used cards in the output. If so then try to configure monitors in system preferences. If You cannot set monitors via user preferences then try to create xorg.conf file and set it manually. Please see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96753/two-ati-radeon-cards-on-10-04/97855#97855) for further details about xorg.conf and setting two different VGA cards.

Answer (score 0):

Get a Kernel Newer/equal 3.8 from

> http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

that did it for me (1xintel, 2xnvidia). The intel driver was crap before when it comes to different video-cards. Since that kernel, it simply works. But i dont know, if the kernel works together with 11.10, but worth a try.
Nevertheless there should be no other limitation to monitor-counts than problems like the intel-driver ;-)