# Window manager won't boot using Nvidia GPU on EEEPC1015PN with Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, intel-graphics, bumblebee, hybrid-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 on an Asus EEEPC 1015PN. This netbook has an Nvidia Ion GPU, which I had to install Mtrons scripts in order to use (located here: https://sites.google.com/site/mtrons/howtos/eeepc-1015pn). These worked great at first and I much prefer the Nvidia mode for Steam and Minecraft and other gaming.

However today I tested out the Intel mode and it also works great. But I restarted in order to go back to the Nvidia mode and it doesn't boot to the window manager, instead it just drops me into `tty1`. The only way I can get to a GUI is by using the Intel mode and now I'm basically stuck in Intel mode. I tried restarting many times and also have tried the commands from Mtron's script such as `sudo display-settings auto` and `sudo display_settings fix` and also `sudo display-settings config-nvidia`. None of those worked. I can't seem to get to the GUI. I would appreciate some advice if anyone has encountered this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please give us output of `sudo lspci | grep VGA`.

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 02)

Comment: Could you please put here an information if anything is written in 7th terminal? ( `Alt+Ctrl+F7` ) If not then please write `start x` and let us know what is the output

Comment: everything is normal but there are a couple lines that talk about the GPU issue. For example at the top it says: `Starting Bumblebee supporting nVidia Optimus Cards [fail]` then a bunch of [OK]s and further down it says `No suitable module for kernel found [fail]` and the last one further down after a few [OK]s says `Starting load fallback graphics devices [fail]` Sorry if this doesn't help, I wasn't sure what to write exactly

Comment: try to generate Xorg.conf file (`sudo Xorg -configure`) and put the output here. Path to this file will be prompted to the screen.

Comment: Silly question but how can I copy and paste the output if I am in a terminal?

Comment: it is easier to copy the file `cp path_to_file_to_be_copied path_to_the_destination`. You can try to use `nano` to copy or write the file to another file `destination_file < cat file_to_be_displayed`

Comment: Sorry, that went over my head. Copy which file? Xorg.conf? How would I go about copying the output? It shows after -configure `number of created screens does not match number of detected devices. Configuration failed. Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.`

Comment: Can you find file Xorg.conf? Does it exist?

Comment: It's in its usual place at /etc/X11/xorg.conf.

Comment: Ok, so it should look something like the one in [that post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/96753/two-ati-radeon-cards-on-10-04/97855#97855). Get to directory containing this file and use `sudo nano xorg.conf`. If you find a device section describing your other (non-nvidia) card then remove it. And check if there is a device section for your nvidia card. Check if your screen uses proper card (device in screen section should be exactly the same as identifier in device section).

Comment: The device section contains the correct drivers and there is no section for the intel driver. And the driver in the screen section points to the correct driver.

Comment: Ok, simply try to delete xorg.conf file and reboot.

Comment: I deleted `xorg.conf` and the same thing happened, it won't give me a GUI. Also `tty7` shows the same errors. There are several `xorg.conf` files located in the folder such as `xorg.conf.asus1015pn.intel` `.nvidia` `.optimushdmi` and `.backup`

Comment: Okay I uninstalled and reinstalled the nvidia-319 driver. Now I can get to the GUI but only with a 640 x 480 resolution. I used `sudo lspci | grep VGA` and it shows the correct driver now. I tried to to run the `nvidia-settings` app to change the resolution and it says I need to run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` in order to continue. I did this and restarted and tried nvidia-settings again. No dice, still says it appears that I am not using an nvidia driver. At least I'm getting closer, any thoughts?

Comment: Did you install this driver trough Jockey?

Answer (score 0):

This should have been a bugreport and not a question suitable for this site but well, here we are ;) Next time, use the integrated "report a bug" wizard in the gui. So we can make sure bug reports reach me.

This bug happened because the driver naming schema for the nvidia binary driver package changed from 'nvidia-current' to nvidia-< first 3 digits of driver version>. The scripts are updated now and work with the new schema, so update to the latest version (assuming you already added the [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~mtron/+archive/eee1015pn) run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ) and run

```
sudo display-settings regenerate-glx
```